How to write a generic component in TSX that accepts an array of types for each DocumentNode passed as a parameter
Below is a generic component that accepts the type of the GraphQL query along with the type of its variables, and as parameters the DocumentNode, the query variables, and a function that takes the data extracted from the query and returns a React.ReactNode.
// RenderData.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { OperationVariables, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

interface Props<T1, T2> {
  query: DocumentNode;
  variables: T2;
  renderData: (data: T1) => React.ReactNode;
}

const RenderData = <T1, T2 extends OperationVariables>({ query, variables, renderData }: Props<T1, T2>) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<T1, T2>(query, {
    variables,
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  }

  return <div>{data && renderData(data)}</div>;
};

export default RenderData;

// App.tsx

...
<RenderData<CustomersQuery, CustomersQueryVariables>
  query={CUSTOMERS_QUERY}
  variables={{ pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 0 }}
  renderData={(data) => <>{JSON.stringify(data.customers.data)}</>}
/>
...

Is it possible to write a component that accepts an array of queries? With a corresponding array of types for each query passed.
The RenderData component should be called like this:
<RenderData<
  [CustomersQuery, CustomersQueryVariables],
  [SuppliersQuery, SuppliersQueryVariables]
>
  queries={[CUSTOMERS_QUERY, SUPPLIERS_QUERY_]}
  variables={{ pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 0 }}
  renderData={(data) => <>{JSON.stringify(data)}</>}
/>

I expect the renderData function typing to be as follows:
(data: [CustomersQuery, SuppliersQuery]) => React.ReactNode

